# Unexpected sign of a regression coefficient; how should I interpret this result?

Tags: r, interpretation, mlogit

I estimated a multinomial logit model for travel mode choice on my dataset. The sign of the beta parameter for the "bus_cost" variable is positive. But a positive sign does not make sense, since as the price of the bus increases, the utility of it should decrease. The standard error of this variable is also too big.

20 out of 153 individuals chose bus as their mode choice. While bus_time varied among these individuals, the price for all the 20 individuals was the same. Is this the reason that I get this unexpected sign?

Here is part of my code in R, and the results.

```r
Bus utility  = asc_BUS + B_bus_cost* bus_cost + 
    B_bus_time*bus_time
```

```r
                        Estimate      s.e.      t.rat.(0)   Rob.s.e.   Rob.t.rat.(0)
B_bus_cost              3.43610     3.66049      0.9387     1.71946      1.998361
B_bus_time             -0.08302     0.03483     -2.3839     0.03557     -2.333819
```

Comment: Tell us more about your data, what are those variables? Are you saying that the "bus cost" variable is constant? If yes, there is no point to include it in analysis.

Comment: The estimate is not statistically significant: you should not interpret it in any other way than that it has  zero effect.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Other variables are drive_time, drive_cost, disability, car_accessibility, walk_time... . No. the bus cost is not constant. All the variables except "Disability" and "car_accessibility" are alternative_specific. I measured alternative_specific variables using GoogleMaps (based on people's home address and their destination address). I want to estimate how much each of these variables affects people's travel mode choices.